# Custom shader on object not correct when object is rotating

Tags: javascript, three.js, glsl

https://codepen.io/im_paul_hi/pen/bObYOy?editors=0010

I am trying to write a basic diffuse lighting shader, but when I apply any kind of position/rotation change on my object, the shading doesn't seem to be getting updated.  If I move the "Custom Point Light" position, it seems to be working ok (the shading on the cube updates accurately), but if the cube itself is moving, the shading does not look correct.

If you uncomment lines 183 and 184, the rotation is applied, and the shading is not correct.

```
cube.rotation.x += rotSpeed.x;
cube.rotation.y += rotSpeed.y;
```

```js
class PromisedLoad {

  static GenericLoader(loader, url, callback) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      loader.load(url, (object) => {
        if (callback) {
          callback(object, resolve);
        } else {
          resolve(object);
        }
      }, (progress) => {
        console.log(progress);
      }, (error) => {
        reject(error);
      });
    });
  }

  static GetGLTF(url, callback) {
    let gltfLoader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();
    return this.GenericLoader(gltfLoader, url, callback);
  }


}

let vertexShader2 = `
uniform float time;
uniform vec3 materialColor;
uniform vec3 ambientLightColor;
uniform float ambientLightStrength;
uniform vec3 customPointLightPos;

varying vec3 vNormal;
varying vec3 lightVec;

void main() {
  // normal is an attribute passed in by threejs
  vNormal = normal;
  lightVec = normalize(customPointLightPos - position);
 

  gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(position,1.0);
}
`;

// import customFragmentShader from './shaders/fragmentShader1.glsl';
let fragmentShader1 = `
uniform float time;
uniform vec3 materialColor;
uniform vec3 ambientLightColor;
uniform float ambientLightStrength;
uniform vec3 customPointLightPos;

varying vec3 vNormal;
varying vec3 lightVec;

void main() {
  float dProd = max(0.0, dot(vNormal, lightVec));
  vec3 c = mix(materialColor * dProd, ambientLightColor, ambientLightStrength);
  gl_FragColor = vec4(c, 1.0);
}
`;

let mouse = new THREE.Vector2();

window.addEventListener('mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove, false);

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  let renderer,
    camera,
    scene = null;
  const container = document.getElementById('container');
  let controls;
  let startTime, time;
  let cube;
  let rotSpeed = new THREE.Vector3(0.05, 0.03, 0.0);
  let axesHelper;
  let uniforms;
  let customPointLight;

  initialize();

  // console.log('rotSpeed:  ', rotSpeed);
  // setupGUI();

  async function initialize() {
    scene = new THREE.Scene();
    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
      antialias: true // to get smoother output
    });
    renderer.setClearColor(0x3b3b3b);
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

    // create a camera in the scene
    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
      35,
      window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight,
      1,
      10000
    );

    axesHelper = new THREE.AxesHelper(5);
    scene.add(axesHelper);

    addCube();

    addCustomPointLight();

    controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera);
    scene.add(camera);
    camera.position.z = 5;
    controls.update();

    // and then just look at it!
    camera.lookAt(scene.position);
    controls.update();

    animate();
  }

  function addCube() {
    // let geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(1, 32, 32);
    let geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1,1,1);
    uniforms = {
      time: {
        type: 'f',
        value: 0
      },
      materialColor: {
        type: 'v3f',
        value: new THREE.Vector3(1.0, 0.0, 0.0)
      },
      ambientLightColor: {
        type: 'v3f',
        value: new THREE.Vector3(0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
      },
      ambientLightStrength: {
        type: 'f',
        value: 0.3
      },
      customPointLightPos: {
        type: 'v3f',
        value: new THREE.Vector3(2.0, 2.0, 2.0)
      }
    };
    const shaderMaterialParams = {
      uniforms: uniforms,
      vertexShader: vertexShader2,
      fragmentShader: fragmentShader1
    };
    const customMaterial = new THREE.ShaderMaterial(shaderMaterialParams);

    cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, customMaterial);
    scene.add(cube);
  }

  function addCustomPointLight() {
    let geo = new THREE.BoxGeometry(0.3, 0.3, 0.3);
    let mat = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial();
    customPointLight = new THREE.Mesh(geo, mat);
    customPointLight.position.set(2, 2, 2);
    scene.add(customPointLight);
  }

  function normalize(x, fromMin, fromMax) {
    let totalRange;

    x = Math.abs(x);
    totalRange = Math.abs(fromMin) + Math.abs(fromMax);
    // now we can map out the range from 0 to the totalRange and get a normalized (0 - 1) value
    return x / totalRange;
  }

  function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);

    time = performance.now() / 1000;

    cube.material.uniforms.time.value = time;

    cube.rotation.x += rotSpeed.x;
    cube.rotation.y += rotSpeed.y;

    render();
  }

  function render() {
    renderer.render(scene, camera);

    controls.update();
  }

  setupGUI(rotSpeed, uniforms, cube, customPointLight);
});

function setupGUI(rotSpeed, uniforms, cube, customPointLight) {
  let options = {
    velx: 0,
    vely: 0,
    rotSpeed: rotSpeed,
    materialColor: uniforms.materialColor.value.toArray(),
    ambientLightColor: uniforms.ambientLightColor.value.toArray(),
    ambientLightStrength: uniforms.ambientLightStrength.value,
    customPointLightPos: {
      x: 2,
      y: 2,
      z: 2
    }
  };
  let gui = new dat.GUI();
  let rotation = gui.addFolder('Rotation');
  rotation
    .add(options.rotSpeed, 'x', -0.02, 0.02)
    .name('X')
    .listen();
  rotation
    .add(options.rotSpeed, 'y', -0.02, 0.02)
    .name('Y')
    .listen();
  rotation.open();
  let uniformsGUI = gui.addFolder('Uniforms');
  uniformsGUI
    .addColor(options, 'materialColor')
    .onChange(function(value) {
      cube.material.uniforms.materialColor.value.x = value[0] / 255;
      cube.material.uniforms.materialColor.value.y = value[1] / 255;
      cube.material.uniforms.materialColor.value.z = value[2] / 255;
    })
    .name('materialColor')
    .listen();
  uniformsGUI.addColor(options, 'ambientLightColor').onChange(function(value) {
    cube.material.uniforms.ambientLightColor.value.x = value[0] / 255;
    cube.material.uniforms.ambientLightColor.value.y = value[1] / 255;
    cube.material.uniforms.ambientLightColor.value.z = value[2] / 255;
  });
  uniformsGUI
    .add(options, 'ambientLightStrength', 0.0, 1.0)
    .onChange(function(value) {
      cube.material.uniforms.ambientLightStrength.value = value;
    });
  uniformsGUI.open();

  let customPointLightGUI = gui.addFolder('Custom Point Light');
  customPointLightGUI
    .add(customPointLight.position, 'x', -5, 5)
    .onChange(function(value) {
      cube.material.uniforms.customPointLightPos.value.x = value;
    });
  customPointLightGUI
    .add(customPointLight.position, 'y', -5, 5)
    .onChange(function(value) {
      cube.material.uniforms.customPointLightPos.value.y = value;
    });
  customPointLightGUI
    .add(customPointLight.position, 'z', -5, 5)
    .onChange(function(value) {
      cube.material.uniforms.customPointLightPos.value.z = value;
    });
  customPointLightGUI.open();

  let box = gui.addFolder('Cube');
  box
    .add(cube.scale, 'x', 0, 3)
    .name('Width')
    .listen();
  box
    .add(cube.scale, 'y', 0, 3)
    .name('Height')
    .listen();
  box
    .add(cube.scale, 'z', 0, 3)
    .name('Length')
    .listen();
  box.add(cube.material, 'wireframe').listen();
  box.open();
}

function onDocumentMouseMove(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  mouse.x = (event.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1;
  mouse.y = -(event.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1;
}
```

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 100%;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: lighter;
    background: grey;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}

a{
    color: inherit;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/98/three.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/three@0.97/examples/js/loaders/GLTFLoader.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/three@0.97/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
<!--https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/98/three.js-->
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is caused, because in the fragment shader `vNormal` is a vector in model spac and `position` is point in model space, while `customPointLightPos` is a position in world space.

You have to transform `vNormal` from model space to view space in the vertex shader. this can be done by the [`normalMatrix`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/renderers/webgl/WebGLProgram), which is provided by THREE.js.
To calculate the light vector, you have to transform the `position` from model space to view space, which can be done by the [`modelViewMatrix`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/renderers/webgl/WebGLProgram).
And you have to transform `customPointLightPos` from world space to view space, which can be done by the [`viewMatrix`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/renderers/webgl/WebGLProgram):

```c
vNormal           = normalMatrix * normal;
vec4 viewPos      = modelViewMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);
vec4 viewLightPos = viewMatrix * vec4(customPointLightPos, 1.0);
lightVec          = normalize(viewLightPos.xyz - viewPos.xyz);
```

This causes that both vectors are related tor the same reference system and can be compared respectively used for the light calculations.

See the eaxmaple, wher I applied the suggested changes to your original code:

```js
class PromisedLoad {

static GenericLoader(loader, url, callback) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    loader.load(url, (object) => {
      if (callback) {
        callback(object, resolve);
      } else {
        resolve(object);
      }
    }, (progress) => {
      console.log(progress);
    }, (error) => {
      reject(error);
    });
  });
}

static GetGLTF(url, callback) {
  let gltfLoader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();
  return this.GenericLoader(gltfLoader, url, callback);
}


}

let vertexShader2 = `
uniform float time;
uniform vec3 materialColor;
uniform vec3 ambientLightColor;
uniform float ambientLightStrength;
uniform vec3 customPointLightPos;

varying vec3 vNormal;
varying vec3 lightVec;

void main() {

    vNormal           = normalMatrix * normal;
    vec4 viewPos      = modelViewMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);
    vec4 viewLightPos = viewMatrix * vec4(customPointLightPos, 1.0);
    lightVec          = normalize(viewLightPos.xyz - viewPos.xyz);

    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(position,1.0);
}
`;

// import customFragmentShader from './shaders/fragmentShader1.glsl';
let fragmentShader1 = `
uniform float time;
uniform vec3 materialColor;
uniform vec3 ambientLightColor;
uniform float ambientLightStrength;
uniform vec3 customPointLightPos;

varying vec3 vNormal;
varying vec3 lightVec;

void main() {
float dProd = max(0.0, dot(vNormal, lightVec));
vec3 c = mix(materialColor * dProd, ambientLightColor, ambientLightStrength);
gl_FragColor = vec4(c, 1.0);
}
`;

let mouse = new THREE.Vector2();

window.addEventListener('mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove, false);

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
let renderer,
  camera,
  scene = null;
const container = document.getElementById('container');
let controls;
let startTime, time;
let cube;
let rotSpeed = new THREE.Vector3(0.05, 0.03, 0.0);
let axesHelper;
let uniforms;
let customPointLight;

initialize();

// console.log('rotSpeed:  ', rotSpeed);
// setupGUI();

async function initialize() {
  scene = new THREE.Scene();
  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    antialias: true // to get smoother output
  });
  renderer.setClearColor(0x3b3b3b);
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

  // create a camera in the scene
  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
    35,
    window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight,
    1,
    10000
  );

  axesHelper = new THREE.AxesHelper(5);
  scene.add(axesHelper);

  addCube();

  addCustomPointLight();

  controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera);
  scene.add(camera);
  camera.position.z = 10;
  controls.update();

  // and then just look at it!
  camera.lookAt(scene.position);
  controls.update();
  window.onresize = resize;

  animate();
}

function resize() {
    
    var aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    camera.aspect = aspect;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
  }

function addCube() {
  // let geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(1, 32, 32);
  let geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1,1,1);
  uniforms = {
    time: {
      type: 'f',
      value: 0
    },
    materialColor: {
      type: 'v3f',
      value: new THREE.Vector3(1.0, 0.0, 0.0)
    },
    ambientLightColor: {
      type: 'v3f',
      value: new THREE.Vector3(0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
    },
    ambientLightStrength: {
      type: 'f',
      value: 0.3
    },
    customPointLightPos: {
      type: 'v3f',
      value: new THREE.Vector3(2.0, 2.0, 2.0)
    }
  };
  const shaderMaterialParams = {
    uniforms: uniforms,
    vertexShader: vertexShader2,
    fragmentShader: fragmentShader1
  };
  const customMaterial = new THREE.ShaderMaterial(shaderMaterialParams);

  cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, customMaterial);
  scene.add(cube);
}

function addCustomPointLight() {
  let geo = new THREE.BoxGeometry(0.3, 0.3, 0.3);
  let mat = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial();
  customPointLight = new THREE.Mesh(geo, mat);
  customPointLight.position.set(2, 2, 2);
  scene.add(customPointLight);
}

function normalize(x, fromMin, fromMax) {
  let totalRange;

  x = Math.abs(x);
  totalRange = Math.abs(fromMin) + Math.abs(fromMax);
  // now we can map out the range from 0 to the totalRange and get a normalized (0 - 1) value
  return x / totalRange;
}

function animate() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);

  time = performance.now() / 1000;

  cube.material.uniforms.time.value = time;

  cube.rotation.x += rotSpeed.x;
  cube.rotation.y += rotSpeed.y;

  render();
}

function render() {
  renderer.render(scene, camera);

  controls.update();
}

setupGUI(rotSpeed, uniforms, cube, customPointLight);
});

function setupGUI(rotSpeed, uniforms, cube, customPointLight) {
let options = {
  velx: 0,
  vely: 0,
  rotSpeed: rotSpeed,
  materialColor: uniforms.materialColor.value.toArray(),
  ambientLightColor: uniforms.ambientLightColor.value.toArray(),
  ambientLightStrength: uniforms.ambientLightStrength.value,
  customPointLightPos: {
    x: 2,
    y: 2,
    z: 2
  }
};
let gui = new dat.GUI();
let rotation = gui.addFolder('Rotation');
rotation
  .add(options.rotSpeed, 'x', -0.02, 0.02)
  .name('X')
  .listen();
rotation
  .add(options.rotSpeed, 'y', -0.02, 0.02)
  .name('Y')
  .listen();
rotation.open();
let uniformsGUI = gui.addFolder('Uniforms');
uniformsGUI
  .addColor(options, 'materialColor')
  .onChange(function(value) {
    cube.material.uniforms.materialColor.value.x = value[0] / 255;
    cube.material.uniforms.materialColor.value.y = value[1] / 255;
    cube.material.uniforms.materialColor.value.z = value[2] / 255;
  })
  .name('materialColor')
  .listen();
uniformsGUI.addColor(options, 'ambientLightColor').onChange(function(value) {
  cube.material.uniforms.ambientLightColor.value.x = value[0] / 255;
  cube.material.uniforms.ambientLightColor.value.y = value[1] / 255;
  cube.material.uniforms.ambientLightColor.value.z = value[2] / 255;
});
uniformsGUI
  .add(options, 'ambientLightStrength', 0.0, 1.0)
  .onChange(function(value) {
    cube.material.uniforms.ambientLightStrength.value = value;
  });
uniformsGUI.open();

let customPointLightGUI = gui.addFolder('Custom Point Light');
customPointLightGUI
  .add(customPointLight.position, 'x', -5, 5)
  .onChange(function(value) {
    cube.material.uniforms.customPointLightPos.value.x = value;
  });
customPointLightGUI
  .add(customPointLight.position, 'y', -5, 5)
  .onChange(function(value) {
    cube.material.uniforms.customPointLightPos.value.y = value;
  });
customPointLightGUI
  .add(customPointLight.position, 'z', -5, 5)
  .onChange(function(value) {
    cube.material.uniforms.customPointLightPos.value.z = value;
  });
customPointLightGUI.open();

let box = gui.addFolder('Cube');
box
  .add(cube.scale, 'x', 0, 3)
  .name('Width')
  .listen();
box
  .add(cube.scale, 'y', 0, 3)
  .name('Height')
  .listen();
box
  .add(cube.scale, 'z', 0, 3)
  .name('Length')
  .listen();
box.add(cube.material, 'wireframe').listen();
box.open();
}

function onDocumentMouseMove(event) {
event.preventDefault();
mouse.x = (event.clientX / window.innerWidth) * 2 - 1;
mouse.y = -(event.clientY / window.innerHeight) * 2 + 1;
}
```

```css
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 100%;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: lighter;
    background: grey;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/99/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/loaders/GLTFLoader.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```